# Beautiful Soup - selecting text of next span element with no class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to use Beautiful Soup to scrape movie quotes from rottentomatoes.com. The page source is interesting in that the quotes are directly proceeded by a span class "bold quote_actor", but the quote itself is in a span with no class, e.g. (https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/happy_gilmore/quotes/):
[screenshot of web source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsm9H.jpg)

I would like to use Beautiful Soup's find_all to capture all quotes, without the actor's name. I have tried many things with no success, such as:

```html
moviequotes = soup(input)
for t in web_soup.findAll('span', {'class':'bold quote_actor'}):
    for item in t.parent.next_siblings:
        if isinstance(item, Tag):
            if 'class' in item.attrs and 'name' in item.attrs['class']:
                break
            print (item)
```

I would greatly appreciate any tips for how to navigate this code and to define the resulting plain text quotes into an object I use use with Pandas, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using CSS selectors to find the `spans` which contain quotes: `div span + span`. This finds any `span` element that is inside a `div` and has a direct sibling element of type `span`.

This way I also get the `span`s that contain actor names, so I filter them out by checking if they have a `class` or `style` attribute.

```
import bs4
import requests

url  = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/happy_gilmore/quotes/'
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

# CSS selector
selector = 'div span + span'

# find all the span elements which are a descendant of a div element
# and are a direct sibling of another span element 
quotes = soup.select(selector)

# now filter out the elements with actor names
data = []

for q in quotes:
    # only keep elements that don't have a class or style attribute
    if not (q.has_attr('class') or q.has_attr('style')):
        data.append(q)

for d in data:
    print(d.text)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. I learned a lot from closely reviewing your answer.